# My animation function is playing up

Tags: javascript, html, animation, opacity

Hey, I have been working on this [animation function](https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/dev/src/animate.js) for my JavaScript library for a little while now and I have found a fairly large problem.

When animating *any* property it works fine, no problems, no errors other than the opacity. If you go to animate the opacity nothing happens until you also animate another property.

For instance, this will not work.

```
Spark('p#opacity').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1000);
```

But this will

```
Spark('p#opacity').animate({opacity: 0.5, marginTop: 1}, 1000);
```

So after reading through the function I linked above, have you noticed anything blatantly wrong? It is to do with all of the cross browser fixes I have had to do when animating opacity. As you can see I am having to set four types of opacity etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only get it to work by changing making sure that `prefix` and `unit` were set to `''` rather than `undefined` or `false`.

It would set values like `undefined.2false` for the opacity.  One caveat, I ran it outside of the rest of the library, so there may be something I missed.

Comment: This looks very interesting! I will test it tomorrow (it is 11 at night here) morning and up vote / accept accordingly.

Comment: You absolute genius. I would never had thought that was the problem. It is all working perfectly now so thank you!